# msg.exe Title of Dialog box

Tags: windows

When using `msg.exe` to send message to another computer, the default title of the dialog box shown on target computers is *Message from [USERNAME] [DATE] [TIME]*. Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no command line switches that control the title, so it looks like a no.